# How to find elements whose children do not contain a specific character

Tags: xpath

I have 15 `<record>` that contain various children, and when I use;

```
//record[*/contains(text(), '{')]
```

I find the 5 that contains the char "{"

But if I try to find the 10 that do not by using;

```
//record[*/not(contains(text(), '{'))]
```

it returns all 15 elements, because I guess as soon as one of children do not contain it, it is returned as a match.

How can I find the 10 records that do not contain this char in any of the children?

Comment: oops, did not escaped the tags, it should say; I have 15 "Record" element...

Comment: Please show a minimal but complete sample of the XML input document and show which elements you want to select with the first XPath and which ones with the second XPath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPaths are searching `record` elements containing elements that contain *text nodes* that do or do not contain the `{` character.  This is not what you want.

Instead, test against the *string value* of each `record` directly:

```
//record[contains(., '{')]
```

and

```
//record[not(contains(., '{'))]
```

In this way you'll get the 5 (contains) + 10 (doesn't contain) = 15 (total) matches that you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kenneth!